# Move semantics from one type to another using templates

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, c++14, move-semantics

Is it possible to have a `struct A` with a move constructor for itself and some constructor which can move from other types (e.g `struct B` ) but with having a template deduction going on such that the type `B` is not hardcoded directly as another move constructor:

```
 struct A{
      A()= default;
      A(A&&a){ /* A's move constructor */ }

      template<typename T>
      A(T&&t){ 
        /* (not a move constructor! by std., matches also lvalues) 

        move from t
        (meta programming to check if we can move the type) 
        */
      } 


}

struct B{};
```

the problem with the above is that

```
B b;
A a(std::move(b)); // select the templated constructor (which moves)

A a(b);  // selects the same copy constructor (which moves but we do not want!!
```

How does one achieve this?

Comment: note that `T&&t` is a *forwarding reference*, it allows `T` to deduce to reference types (unlike `A(B&& b`)` ). So this constructor will actually also match lvalues.

Comment: thats the exact problem I have how to distinguish this, but with keeping the template deduction process going on...?

Comment: There's probably some sfinae trick but I can't think of anything. It would be a subject for another question !

Comment: Argggghhhh your question changed. FFS.

Comment: @Gabriel I'd strongly suggest rolling back to the original question and posting the new question separately, what you have done is just annoying

Comment: sorry I posted to early and was not finished, I am sorry, giving you anyway thumbs up for your answer!

Comment: I need to take more care befor posting, next time!

Comment: What constructor should `A a(b)` select?  Should it be an error?  Should there be a different constructor that matches it?

Answer (score 4):

The cleanest solution is to create a better constructor for lvalues, then `=delete` it:

```
struct A{
  A()= default;
  A(A&&a){ /* A's move constructor */ }

  template<class T>
  A(T&&t){ 
  } 
  template<class T>
  A(T const&&)=delete;
  template<class T>
  A(T&t)=delete;
};
```

under this method, `A a(b);` will fail to compile.

If you want lvalues to follow a different path, then:

```
struct A{
  A()= default;
  A(A&&a){ /* A's move constructor */ }

  template<class T>
  A(T&&t){ 
    // rvalues end up here
  } 
  template<class T>
  A(T const&&t):A(t) {} // forward to lvalue ctor
  template<class T>
  A(T&t){
    // lvalues end up here
  }
};
```

the use of SFINAE is probably only worth the complexity *if* you don't know which of these two options you are going to want -- ie, where you are inheriting constructors from elsewhere.

There is a final corner case -- `A(T const&&)` (and `A(A const&&)`) which can crop up in some corner cases.  I made it act like an lvalue ctor, as you cannot "move from" a `T const&&` usually.  (unless the guts of the `T` are `mutable`, and even then I'd consider it a bad idea).

Comment: Isn't it enough to just delete the T& constructor? Wouldn't it also work for const T&?

Comment: @Yam `T const&&` will match `T&&` better than `T&`.  `T const&&` is somewhat strange, but for example `int const foo() { return 3; }` has a `const` rvalue return type.  It is strange and rare enough that you could probably neglect to think about it and not see a problem from it for years or more in a large, active code base, and when you did see it happen it would probably be the symptom of some other code being pear-shaped.  But a more concrete example, a `tuple<const int>` being passed as an rvalue: `std::get<0>(std::forward<Tup>(tup))` will be a `int const&&` I think.

Comment: @Yakk For some reasons, the type of `foo()` is not `int const`, but `int` (since `int` is a fundamental type, see [expr]/6). But your argument works for class types.

Comment: @Yakk Oops, didn't see that second & there, I thought you were deleting both T& and const T&. Sorry.

Comment: @dyp C++ is, if nothing less, a silly language.  :)  My bad, I should never ever use `int` when talking about lvalues and rvalues and `const` unless I want to talk about the exceptions that built-in types entail.  Almost as bad as if I made a function returning an array.  >_> <_<

Comment: (Well it fits into the weird scheme of prvalues of fundamental types being values, not objects. For values, cv-qualification doesn't make sense. Binding prvalues of fundamental type to a reference creates a new object. I can't see a way to observe this, though.)

Answer (score 2):

If you want the constructor template to accept arbitrary rvalues, you can use `enable_if`:

```
template <
  class T,
  class Sfinae = typename std::enable_if<!std::is_lvalue_reference<T>::value>::type
>
A(T &&t)
```

This will enable the constructor only if `T` was not deduced to an lvalue reference, which is equivalent to saying that the argument was not an lvalue.

As @dyp mentioned in the comments, it can also be expressed more explicitly:

```
template <
  class T,
  class Sfinae = typename std::enable_if<std::is_rvalue_reference<T&&>::value>::type
>
A(T &&t)
```

Comment: awesome , so in this way SFINAE helps to only have rvalues accepted :-)
that was I looking for

Comment: SFINAE works for default template argument? `typename std::enable_if<!std::is_lvalue_reference<T>::value>::type* = nullptr` seems to be the commonly-used pattern.

Comment: Anyway, a compiler error happens in either case. But the error message generated by using `typename std::enable_if<!std::is_lvalue_reference<T>::value>::type* = nullptr` should be more suggestive.

Comment: @Lingxi Yes, SFINAE works for template arguments just fine. I prefer this one because to me, it's more obvious than buried in the function parameters; but you can use whichever you like more. Clang, for example, generates really nice messages for both. If you really care about the error message, you could add an overload which would accept the lvalue references only, and `static_assert` inside it.

Comment: Instead of using a negative check, why not test `std::is_rvalue_reference<T&&>::value`?

Comment: @dyp Because it didn't occur to me to check something other than bare `T`. Yours works perfectly fine, too.

Comment: If you like it more, you can actually remove "Sfinae" and make it a nameless parameter, to make its sfinaeishness implicit, but just as obvious. :)

Answer (score 0):

Simply take a `B&&` in the constructor, exactly as you did for `A`.

Comment: this is another solution, if we wanna hardcode that type inside A, yes!
+1